# Identical strings are considered not equal because of encoding

Tags: c#, sharepoint, encoding, csom

I am facing a problem for which I can't think of a solution.

I am getting data from a CSV file to create terms in SharePoint Online using CSOM -- so far so good.
I'm in fact recreating a whole hierarchy of terms in a new term set, so I regularly need to get a `Term` from a `TermCollection` and to do so I use `parent = rootTerms.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == name);` after I have loaded the `TermCollection`.

Everything goes as planned except for a string in particular. When I get the string "Rémunération & avantages", I look for it in the `rootTerms` collection but I find nothing although I check in debug that the string *is* in the collection.

After some thinking I understood that the two strings were not exactly the same because the one in the collection is "Rémunération ＆ avantages". As you can see, the ampersand is not displayed with the same font as previously, it seems.

So here is the thing: the string in the collection has been added to the term set by me, using the exact same string I am looking for in the collection. But then, when I get the string back from SharePoint using CSOM, the ampersand character is not the same anymore. The one from the original string is coded **38** while the one from SharePoint is coded **65286**.

I have a lot of questions about encoding and why SharePoint does that etc. but ultimately, I just need `String.Equals` (or equivalent) to return `true` in this case and similar cases. I obviously can't add a check just for that character as there could be others in the same case.

Does anyone have any information about this behaviour and/or how I can manage to do what I am trying to do?

Thank you for reading all this, I tend to explain the whole story instead of just what needs to be known and it results in looooong posts :-p

Comment: U+0038 and U+FF06 are different characters. This isn't an encoding issue - they are different characters. You could look to normalize the strings, although I don't know offhand whether that would normalize ampersands. As a short term hack, you could always use the `Replace` method: `t => t.Name.Replace('\uff06', '&') == name`.

Comment: You're right, that's not an encoding issue per se, but I don't get why SharePoint changes the character code when I get it back with CSOM.

Comment: looks like you arent the only one with that problem: https://sharepointdragons.com/2013/03/05/sharepoint-2010-problem-adding-term-sets-with-in-their-name/

Answer (score -1):

Try using [Normalize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.normalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on strings before comparision.

Could something like this be acceptable for you?

**Update:**

Ok, Default Normalize doesn't work because they are 2 different unicode charachters. But `NormalizationForm.FormKD` seems to do the trick. Also I've found another way of achieving string uguality by converting them first to ASCII. Check if one of these solutions could work for you

```
internal class Program
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, long count);

    private static bool ByteArrayCompare(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
    {
        return b1.Length == b2.Length && memcmp(b1, b2, b1.Length) == 0;
    }

     private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s1 = "Rémunération & avantages";
        var s2 = "Rémunération ＆ avantages";
        Console.WriteLine(s1.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD) == s2.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD));
        var str1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetBytes(s1);
        var str2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetBytes(s2);
        Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayCompare(str1, str2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work. The ampersands remain the same in each string.

Comment: @Jeahel Yeah, I've tried it just now. I've made some more tries and found another way, but I cannot predict the performance and if generally such approach can be used.